# typescript "this" in passed functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a typescript class defined as so:

```
class Foo extends events.EventEmitter {
  private msg;

  constructor(){
      super();
  }

  public error=(err)=> {
      debug("got an error",err,this.msg.data);
   }


  setup=()=> {
    this.options = {
       error: this.error
    }
  }

  run=()=> {
    let x = require("someothermodule");
    x.run(this.options);
  }
 }
```

the problem I am getting when "**x**" calls the **options.error** function is "*TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined*" , and sure enough, this.data *is* undefined

What I want to know is how to refer to the "proper" *this* in the error function ?

This is the result of a long journey, trying all sorts of options, binding, trying to store this in _this (doesn't work at all!) ;)

Would appreciate any insight - newbie Typescript guy, so perhaps I'm missing something really obvious

thanks

Comment: I don't see any code setting the value of the `msg` field. How do you expect `this.msg` to have a non-`undefined` value if you never change it?

Comment: Try to bind the scope of Foo to the error method when creating the options object: `error: this.error.bind(this)`. I can elaborate if you need more details.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens : sorry, this was just a little code "snippet" - so I didn't flesh out all of the code. apologies

Comment: @FlorianTopf: that seems to work for me - thanks very much

Comment: @jmls Well, there's not a whole lot we can do to help you if we can't see how and when `this.msg` is being set. The code you have will work fine - *assuming* that `this.msg` has a value when `x` calls your error callback.

Comment: @jmls I will put an answer, seems to be an important hint for others.

Comment: Some docs : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html also note that `bind` as recommended in the accepted answer can have bad consequences https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you apply the options with an error callback which is accessing `this` in the class `Foo` you need to bind this scope when applying these options to another function (scope).

Your setup function would have to look like this to make this happen:

```
setup = () => {
    this.options = {
        error: this.error.bind(this)
    }
}
```